# passing variable from random number generator class

Tags: java, function, class, variables, random

Instead of writing:

```
 Random randomGenerator = new Random();
 for (int idx = 5; idx <= 15; ++idx){
 int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(1);
```

each time I need a random number in a function, Is it possible to just pass or call the result from a random number generator class into the function?

For Example, I have one function in particular which is receiving variables from another class

```
favoriteTracks(String fromExampleClass1, String fromExampleClass1again)
```

could I do

```
favoriteTracks(String fromExampleClass1, String fromExampleClass1again, Long fromRNGclass)
```

for clarification:
My one function "favoriteTracks" requires variables passed from "ExampleClass1".
At the same time, I want it to receive a random number as a variable (or call it, whichever is easiest). generated in another class by

```
public static long randomNum(){
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
for (int idx = 5; idx <= 15; ++idx){
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(1);
```

Comment: You can pass the random object itself, you know. e.g. `favoriteTracks(String fromClass1, String fromClass1again, Random rand)`.  But I am not sure if that's what you're asking or not.

Comment: Why don't you create a separate function with those 3 lines of code (and a return statement) and call that each time you need a random number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to encapsulate the behaviour you want in a singleton:

```
public class MyRandom {

    public static final MyRandom myRandom = new MyRandom();

    private Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    public int makeRandom() {

        // put your for loop here if you want, but it is not necessary
        return 5 + randomGenerator.nextInt(11);
    }
}
```

somewhere else ...

```
x = MyRandom.myRandom.makeRandom();
```

That looks like a possible solution for what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is good, thanks so much. but i needed the random to pick a number 5 through 15

Comment: So, to do that you typically generate a number between 0 and ten and then add five. Note that the parameter to nextInt is exclusive (it returns the number below it as a maximum).